# Sql query to Add non digit values of multiple columns into a single column and find the count

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have one table with two columns like this

```
Column1| Column2
  A    |    A
  B    |    C
  D    |    D
```

The out put of the query as i expect is :

```
Name | Count
 A   |  2
 B   |  1
 C   |  1
 D   |  2
```

It is easy to sum two(values) but how do i concatenate nonvalues inside a table.

The query i tried:

select Column1 as Name from table union all select Column2 as Name from Table

I get the combined version of two columns but how am i suuposed to get the count(Name) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work perfectly..

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(t.Name) AS Count

FROM (
select `Column1` as Name from table 
union all 
select `Column2` as Name from table
) t

GROUP BY t.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select Name, Count = count(*)
from (Select Name = column1 from table union all select column2 from table)t 
group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these SQl will help you.

```
select * from (
select column1 as col,count(Column1) as count from table_1 GROUP BY col
union all
select column2 as col, count(Column2) as count from table_1 GROUP BY col ) as table_alias group by col
```

Thank you.